# Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(x) \leq 0$ and $f''(x) \geq 0, \forall x.$ Prove $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(x) \leq 0$ and $f''(x) \geq 0, \forall x.$ Prove $f$ is constant.

May I verify if my proof is correct? Thank you.

Proof: $f'' \geq 0 \implies$$f'$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R} \implies$ there exists interval  $[a,b]$ on which $f$ is monotone.  Assume $f'(x) \geq 0, \forall x \in [a,b]---(*)$

Let $c>b.$ By Mean Value theorem, $\dfrac{f(c)-f(b)}{c-b}= f'(d) \geq 0,$ for some $d \in (b,c). $ So $f(c) \geq f(b).$ Apply similar argument to deduce that $f(x) \geq f(y),$ whenever  $x,y \geq b$ and $x\geq y.$

Since $f'(b) \geq 0,$ if $f'$ is strictly increasing on $(b, \infty)$ , this means $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)= \infty$ and contradicts $f(x) \leq 0,  \forall x.$ Hence, $f'(x) =0, \forall x > b$ and by $(*)$,  we must have $f'(x) = 0, \forall x \geq a.$

Consider $g(x)=-f(x),$ then $g'$ is decreasing on $\mathbb{R}$ and $g'(x) \geq 0, \forall x <a.$ By similar argument above, we must have $g'(x)=0, \forall x <a.$

Comment: Why must $f'(d)\geq 0$?

Comment: Proof idea: $f$ is convex so it lies above its tangents. Their slopes can't be non-zero or else $f$ would have a $+\infty$ limit at $-\infty$ or $+\infty$.

Comment: @user7530: Because $d>b, f'$is increasing and $f'(b) \geq 0.$

Answer (score 1):

I think the main idea is correct, though there is no need for monotone intervals or the mean value theorem.

As you say, $f'$ is increasing. So suppose $f'(k)=c>0$ for some $k$. Then for $x>k$,
$$f(x) = f(k) + \int_k^x f' \geq f(k) + \int_k^x c = f(k)+(x-k)c$$
and 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty>0,$$
a contradiction. Similarly if $f'(k)=c<0$ for some $k$, for $x<k$
$$f(x) = f(k)+\int_k^x f' = f(k)-\int_x^k f'(x) \geq f(k)-(k-x)c$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = \infty > 0.$$
So we must have that $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$.