# $\forall x, f(x)\leq 0$ and $f''(x)\geq 0$ then $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis

Question already asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157966/suppose-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-such-that-fx-leq-0-and-fx-ge), but I want an answer without having defined the notion of the integral. This is #23, p.110 in Fitzpatrick's Advanced Calculus.

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a twice differentiable function such that $f(x)\leq 0$ and $f''(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

So as I was trying to tackle the proof, I noticed that the previous exercise (#22, p.110) might be useful:

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function and there is a positive number $c$ such that $f'(x)\geq c$, for all $x$. Prove that $f(x)\geq f(0)+cx$ if $x\geq 0$ and $f(x)\leq f(0)+cx$ if $x\leq 0$.

I thought it might be useful in the following manner: if we asume $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)\geq 0$, this will geometrically tell us that $f$ is increasing with upwards concavity and therefore cannot be bounded above by $0$. As for the assumption that $f'(x)<0$, I haven't looked at it thoroughly yet but graphically seems impossible.

Thank you.

Comment: What you have written intuitively is correct.  Now you will have to put it in formal terms

Comment: It is possible to have $f'(x)<0$ and $f''(x) \geq 0$, but you will have the same problem that $f$ cannot be bounded above by $0$ because as you move to the _left_, $f$ increases and is concave up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $f$ is not constant, there exists a point $a$ with $f'(a) \not= 0$. Assume without loss of generality that $f'(a) > 0$.

Since $f''(x) \ge 0$, the first derivative $f'$ is nondecreasing. Thus $c > a$ implies $f'(c) \ge f'(a)$.  Now employ the mean value theorem. If $x > a$ then there exists a point $c \in (a,x)$ with the property that 
$$f(x) - f(a) = f'(c) (x-a) \ge f'(a)(x-a).$$ Thus
$$x > a \implies f(x) \ge f(a) + f'(a)(x-a).$$

If $x$ is large enough you get $f(x) > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is not constant, there exists a point $a$ with $f'(a) \not= 0$. Assume without loss of generality that $f'(a) > 0$. Since $f$ is twice differentiable, we can write
$$ f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac12f''(c)(x-a)^2, c\text{ is between $a$ and $x$}. $$
Thus for large $x>a$, then $LHS\le0$ and $RHS>0$, which is contradictory each other.